# What is the best analysis to perform on brute force tests?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, minitab

Basically, I have run a network simulation for video streaming a number of times. I have assigned weights to particular performance metrics of the network measuring their performance each time. Depending on the weight configuration, the outputted quality of the video (measured in a mean opinion score or MOS) is different each time.

What I want to know is which metric was most important for a good MOS and which metric was the least important for a good MOS score. I am not very good at statistics so if I wanted to show this which test should I perform in Minitab?

The test was run 16 times, with the weights selected at random.

EDIT: To go into more detail, my results showed that high values for at least two of three particular performance metrics resulted in one of the highest results. How do I represent this?